# Full match only if the capturing group encountered once

Tags: regex, capturing-group

The pattern:

```
(test):(thestring)
```

What I want is full match only if there is just one `test:` before

```
test:thestring
```

But in this case there wouldn't be full match:

```
test:test:thestring
```

I've tried qualificator, but it didn't work.

Need help

Comment: Use a negative lookahead to ensure that `test` isn't followed by `test`

Comment: I still have full match : (?!(test:) ) (thestring)  gives full match thestring

Comment: Can you post the regex you currently have? (also what language are you using?)

Comment: C#, the regex: (test) : (thestring),  the example: test:test:thestring should not match

Comment: A little unsure about the example but a negative lookbehind at the start of the string ensures there is only `test:thestring` matches (this is a very specific case):
`(?<!.)(test:thestring)`.... [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XK0BYH/3)

Comment: Yes,  exactly!  Now I'm trying to understand what i did wrong. I must ensure, that there is only one test before :, could you please explain. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: It doesn't actually check for `test` before the colon, it's checking if there is _anything_ before `test:thestring` and if there is then it will not match. But be aware it **only** matches the string `test:thestring` so wouldn't work with any other data. Michał Turczyn's answer is definitely much more comprehensive, it all depends on what you data is like!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern: `^(?!.*((?(?<=^)|(?<=:))test(?=(:|$))).*(?1)).+$`.

The main part is `((?(?<=^)|(?<=:))test(?=(:|$)))`, which matches `test` if it's preceeded by colon `:` or is at the beginning of a line and it's followed by colon `:` or end of the line.

`(?(?<=^)|(?<=:))` this is workaround to `(?<=(:|^))`, but lookbehinds must have fixed length.

Then we have backreference to first capturing group `(?1)`, to see if there are any other `test`.

This whole pattern is placed in negative lookahead `(?!...)`, to match everything if it doesn't match pattern explained above (`test` matched more than one time).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9a9oot/1)

Comment: In the example it is matching with `asdaf:test:asda` still

Comment: @Nordle You're right,  tried to keep everything as general as possible.

Comment: Yes it's a nice regex, you've got my +1

Answer (score 0):

for this very specific case:

`(?<!.)(test:thestring)`

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XK0BYH/3)

All it does is search for the string `test:thestring` and ensures that there are no characters before it. (Use Michał Turczyn's regex for an all purpose search!)

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?!test:).)*(test:thestring)
```

[See in action](https://regex101.com/r/92iNLU/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full match and there should be only one time test: before test:string you might assert the start of the string `^`,  use a negative lookahead `(?:(?!test:).)` to match any character if what is on the right side is not test:

Then match `test:thestring` followed by a negative lookahead `(?:(?!test:thestring).)*` that matches any character if what is on the right side is not test:thestring and assert the end of the string `$`

`^(?:(?!test:).)*test:thestring(?:(?!test:thestring).)*$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fqCrpx/1/)